Kafka consumer delay while subscribing to a topic occasionally
I'm experiencing a Kafka subscription slowdown with one specific topic ("data-topic") out of three topics published to Kafka brokers. The issue occurs only for "data-topic," which is consumed by a single service, while the other two topics are consumed without delay. The slowdown consistently happens when a large batch of data packets (around 7000-8000 messages) is received, particularly around the 56th minute of every hour, but no data is lost—just delayed.
The same consumer service subscribes to all three topics using a NestJS-based Kafka microservice. Here’s a simplified version of the code for subscribing to the topics:
import { Controller } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Ctx, KafkaContext, MessagePattern, Payload } from "@nestjs/microservices";

@Controller()
export class topicController {
  @MessagePattern("data-topic")
  async dataTopic(@Payload() data: any, @Ctx() context: KafkaContext) {
    console.log("inside data-topic");
  }

  @MessagePattern("topic-2")
  async topic2(@Payload() data: any, @Ctx() context: KafkaContext) {
    console.log("inside topic-2");
  }

  @MessagePattern("topic-3")
  async topic3(@Payload() data: any, @Ctx() context: KafkaContext) {
    console.log("inside topic-3");
  }
}


What could be causing the subscription slowdown for only this specific topic during these periods of high data flow, even though no data is lost? How can I diagnose and resolve this issue? Any suggestions regarding potential Kafka or NestJS configuration issues would be appreciated!
